# Discord: apostrophe in command's argument does not work in C#

Tags: c#, bots, discord, discord.net

I have problem with handling arguments for commands. They work fine until an apostrophe `'` is present in an argument. In that case, nothing happens. Bot does nothing and application won't crash. When I try to debug the command I find out it won't even go to its branch of code.

Example:

`!echo I am fine` works.

But `!echo I'm fine` does not.

My code:

```
client.UsingCommands(input => { 
  input.PrefixChar = '!';
  input.AllowMentionPrefix = true;
});

command = client.GetService<CommandService>();

command.CreateCommand("echo").Parameter("param", ParameterType.Multiple).Do(async (e) => {
  var channel = e.Server.FindChannels(e.Message.Channel.Name, ChannelType.Text).FirstOrDefault();
  string msg = "";
  for (int i = 0; i < e.Args.Length; i++) {
    msg += e.Args[i] + " ";
  }
  msg = msg.Remove(msg.Length - 1);
  await channel.SendMessage(msg);
});
```

Any idea what is happening and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
command.CreateCommand("echo")
               .Description("returns commands")
               .Parameter("message", ParameterType.Unparsed)
               .Do(async (e) =>
               {
                   Message[] messageToDelete;
                   int deleteNumber = 1;
                   messageToDelete = await e.Channel.DownloadMessages(deleteNumber);
                   await e.Channel.DeleteMessages(messageToDelete);

                   var toReturn = $":envelope: | {e.GetArg("message")}";
                   await e.Channel.SendMessage(toReturn);
                   Console.WriteLine(toReturn);
               });
```